# How to install bower package on windows azure website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, bower

I´m deploying this website on azure but I can´t install oauth.io bower package, I get a 404 error (file not found). This is the line for the script source:

```
<script src="./app/bower_components/oauth-js/dist/oauth.min.js"></script>
```

here is the project:

https://github.com/termosfera/tweet-chat

I add the following lines in the deploy.cmd file but still not working:

```
:: 4. Install bower packages
IF EXIST “%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\bower.json” (
  pushd “%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%”
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install bower
  call :ExecuteCmd bower install
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)
```